# fishing wire from second floor to garage in first floor

Tags: wiring, walls

I was trying to drill a 1” hole on the horizontal beam in the wall to fish cable from second floor to garage in first floor. After drilling about 12 inch deep, I cannot go further anymore. Here is few pics about the hole and the wall structure, as well as the drill bit. Please let me know what is going on or if you have any better ideas. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbm5y.jpg)[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDydN.jpg)[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EkfY.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I think that using a spade type of bit there will be really tough going. I would use a regular twist bit. Possibly two if it is really tough going - e.g., 1/2" first and then followup with a 1" through the 1/2" starter hole.

If you have access to do so, it may be easier to drill from the bottom up than from the top down because the hole will empty itself thanks to gravity.

Comment: Drilling from bottom really makes sense. I should have done it that way. I tried to remove the wood dust from the hole by adapting a smaller pipe to my vacuum. I then tried to drill further and I finally made through.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase really long standard twist bits and they also sell flexible ones that allow you to have the drill outside of the cavity. You then bend it into a hole in the floor plate.

I'd drill a smaller one using one of these bits, and assuming that goes well, look to make it larger, perhaps from the bottom.

Obviously make sure there's nothing below you that wouldn't like being drilled into.

Comment: Yes using smaller flexible to do pilot drilling first is quite useful. I'd do this next time if I ever need to.